# Penalty Factor in Generator Dispatching

Tags: power, generator

Can anyone please explain what is meant by penalty factor in generator dispatching (power systems)? I know this is used when we define the Lagrangian equation for non linear variable costs, but don't really understand how it fits in.

Comment: Can you please give us a link to where this was said, some baseline can help users whom are very experienced here resolve what was meant.

Answer (score 2):

A problem is that the term "penalty factor" is used in quit a few ways in the power generation and distribution industry. A number of these are relevant enough to Lagrangian analysis that one can't be sure that they are what you want.As Kortuk says , it would be a good idea to quote a specific example.

---

(0) This paper (abstract only here) -
 [A dual augmented Lagrangian approach for optimal power flow](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel1%2F59%2F569%2F00014556.pdf%3Farnumber%3D14556&authDecision=-203)
 seems to use the term exactly as you intended (I think :-) ).

It says

- The authors present a method for solving the active and reactive optimal power-flow problem. The method is based on nonlinear programming techniques combining dual and penalty approaches. The classical Langrangian is defined for both equality and inequality constraints. The function is then augmented by penalty terms for all constraints and it is minimized by Newton's method. An intrinsic multiplier updating rule eliminates the necessity of increasing the penalty factors to very large values. The method unifies the treatment equality and inequality constraints. It also avoids the critical aspects present in the determination of the binding constraints set

What's not to like ? :-)
 (Runs screaming from room).

====

---

(1) At the most general level the term is used to describe what are effectively 'fiddle factors' added in order to ensure that hard or soft constraints are met when analysis is carried out.

This paper uses the term very much in the context that you mention.
 They introduce

- βγ Penalty factor associated with emission constraint
- βλ Penalty factor associated with power balance
- βη Penalty factor associated with transmission constraint

Here the key point is that they have an iterative solution system which can become unstable during solution and they introduce factors to limit instabilities.

It sounds extremely like magic empirical hand waving. eg on page 80 they say:

- Selection of parameters: In the ALHN model, the parameters 
  have to be predetermined including sigmoid function slope, 
  updating step sizes for neurons and penalty factors for 
  augmented Lagrange function. A proper parameter selection 
  will guarantee rapid convergence to ALHN. The parameters 
  of ALHN are selected via tuning. By experiments, the values 
  of sigmoid function slope and penalty factors are fixed at 100 
  and 0.001, respectively. The values of the others will vary 
  depending on the data of test systems.

---

(2) A slightly more orthodox use is to provide weighting factors for power stations  when performing routing and optimum cost analyses for grids of energy sources. These seem to linearly represent energy losses due to transmission "costs" between nodes. In some instances they seem to use sparate parameters for reactive and resistive components.

====

This abstract for the paper [Transmission loss penalty factors for area energy interchange](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel1%2F59%2F11253%2F00535679.pdf%3Farnumber%3D535679&authDecision=-203)
 says (summarised)

- The concept of transmission loss penalty factors for area energy interchange is introduced...  The algorithm for penalty factors is based upon the Jacobian method ...electrical distances between energy sending and receiving points and the area inter-tie locations are considered in the calculation. ... an area penalty factor ... reflects only the portion of the internal area loss induced by the interchange with the area of interest.

====

[This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0142061502000145) sounds relevant in the same context. For $.

This 5 page 1995 Chilean paper
 [Penalty Factor calculations for marginal pricing of transmission systems in a hydroelectrical system](http://web.ing.puc.cl/~power/paperspdf/penalty.pdf)  looks like it may be especially useful in this context. Not a searchable PDF  unfortunately.

---

(3) Some papers use the term "penalty" factor asa means of providing feasibility weighting

eg see the formula at the bottom of the 3rd page here
 [Short-Term Hydrothermal Generation Scheduling
Model Using a Genetic Algorithm](http://www.wseas.us/conferences/2010/coimbatore/icnvs/643-254.pdf) where panalty is effectovely a linear cost factor.

---

Worth a look.

[Seems somewhat confused re how to treat the term](http://www.usaee.org/usaee2011/submissions/OnlineProceedings/Fernandez_USAEEPaper_2011.pdf)

---

[ECONOMIC DISPATCH WITH EMISSION AND 
TRANSMISSION CONSTRAINTS BY AUGMENTED 
LAGRANGE HOPFIELD NETWOR](http://www.engedu2.net/v1/PO-O32.pdf)

- This paper with abstract given at the end ("Economic disptach with emission ...") proposes an augmented Lagrange Hopfield 
  network (ALHN) for solving economic dispatch (ED) 
  problem with ramp rate, emission and transmission 
  constraints. The proposed ALHN method is the continuous 
  Hopfield neural network with its energy function based on 
  augmented Lagrangian function. In ALHN, the energy 
  function is augmented by Hopfield terms from Hopfield 
  neural network and penalty factors from augmented 
  Lagrangian function to damp out oscillation of the Hopfield 
  network during its convergence.